# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small in while execute immediate

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

We are having an 11.2.0.3 database and I am trying to execute the procedure and it is throwing a error `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small` when it comes to line

```
Execute immediate var1||var2||var3||var4;
```

Here all the variables are declared as long datatype and size varies as below.

Size: 200,300,30200,20100 bytes

What could be the issue. what could be the reason for this error. I see a lot of generic errors.So getting confused.

Thanks
SHIYAS M

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Oracle tries to concatenate VARCHAR data types, because `var1` has got only 200 bytes and thus considered as VARCHAR instead of CLOB.

Maybe this one works:

```
Execute immediate TO_CLOB(var1)||TO_CLOB(var2)||TO_CLOB(var3)||TO_CLOB(var4);
```

Another problem could be your string  itself. Can you output the string and execute manually?

Comment: If I output the string and execute manually, it is working fine. 
All the variables are declared with LONG datatype. Do I need to change it to CLOB. Will that help !

Comment: Quick answer: never use LONG datatype, it is deprecated for ages.